# Creating words from 3 chars

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many 4 characters words cane we make out of A B C when every word has to contian atleast one A and atleast one B?

We are choosing 2 places out of 4 where we but A and B so its 4C2 and we can swap them so * 2 . we are left with 2 places where we can but A B or C , so 3 * 3 , =

4C2 * 2 * 3 * 3 , this results in 108 but it isnt correct answer. What is the right way to calculate it?

Comment: Your method counts many words multiple times! For example ABAB would be counted 4 times and ABAA would be counted 3 times. You need to use PIE to get the right answer!

Answer (score 3):

With principle of inclusion-exclusion:

4 character words with A B C: 3^4=81

4 character words with no A (only B and C): 2^4=16

4 character words with no B (only A and C): 2^4=16

4 character words with no A and no B (only C): 1^4=1

The answer is 81-16-16+1=50

Another way:

Words containing 1A and 1B ${4\choose 1}\cdot{3\choose 1}=12$

Words containing 1A and 2B ${4\choose 1}\cdot{3\choose 2}=12$

Words containing 2A and 1B ${4\choose 2}\cdot{2\choose 1}=12$

Words containing 1A and 3B ${4\choose 1}\cdot{3\choose 3}=4$

Words containing 3A and 1B ${4\choose 3}\cdot{1\choose 1}=4$

Words containing 2A and 2B ${4\choose 2}\cdot{2\choose 2}=6$

Total:50

Comment: Hm.. what is wrong with logic i wrote?

Comment: If you choose 2 places to put A and B, it doesn't mean that those are the only A's and B's in the word. So if you want to solve the problem your way, you have to separately count words having: 1A 1B, 1A 2B, 1A 3B, 2A 1B, 2A 2B, 3A 1B in order to make sure you don't double count.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcounting, suppose you pick A and B to be in the first two spots as follows:
$$AB\text{_}\, \text{_}$$
Then you decide to put A in the third slot and then B in the fourth slot:
$$ABAB.$$

However, this is the same thing as first choosing A and B to be in the third and fourth slot respectively,
$$\text{_}\, \text{_}AB$$

and then deciding to fill the remaining two slots with an A and B:
$$ABAB.$$

One solution that doesn't involve the inclusion-exclusion principle is to break things up into cases:

1. One A, one B, two C's
2. Two A's, one B, one C
3. One A, two B's, one C
4. Two A's, two B's, no C
5. Three A's, one B, no C
6. One A, three B's, no C

For case one, there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to place the C's, and then you have two choices for where to place the A and B in the remaining two slots for a total of $6 \cdot 2 = 12$ possible ways. Case 2 and 3 are symmetric to case 1 so those also have $12$ possible ways.

For case 4, you have ${4 \choose 2}=6$ ways of placing the A's after which the position of the B's are determined so there are only $6$ ways.

For case 5, you have $4$ choices for placing the B after which the positions of the A's will be determined so there are a total of only 4 possibilities for this case. Case 6 is symmmetric to case 5 so it also only has 4 possibilties.

Adding everything up: $12+12+12+6+4+4 = 50$ possibilities.